# Write Custom Error Pages for Every Specfic Status Code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes

If you retrieve an exception (containing stacktrace etc.) you want to display a customized error message.

My question is:

1. Do you need to use status code (404, 500 etc.) in order to NOT to display any exception message?
2. If you have about 60 different status code (http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml), do I need to write specific for each page based on the source code below?

I have used the code from this page "http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages"

I'm using ASP.net mvc 4

Comment: I guess no, what you need to is log those traces